# Flatten and aggregate two columns of arrays via distinct in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table structure is

```
+------------+---------+
|  Animals   |  Herbs  |
+------------+---------+
| [Cat, Dog] | [Basil] |
| [Dog, Lion]| []      |
+------------+---------+
```

Desired output (don't care about sorting of this list):

```
unique_things
+------------+
[Cat, Dog, Lion, Basil]
```

First attempt was something like

```
SELECT ARRAY_CAT(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(animals)), ARRAY_AGG(herbs))
```

But this produces

```
[[Cat, Dog], [Dog, Lion], [Basil], []]
```

Since the distinct is operating on each array, not looking at distinct components within all arrays

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE

It is possible without using FLATTEN, by using [ARRAY_UNION_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_union_agg.html):

> Returns an ARRAY that contains the union of the distinct values from the input ARRAYs in a column.

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t AS
SELECT ['Cat', 'Dog'] AS Animals, ['Basil'] AS Herbs
UNION SELECT ['Dog', 'Lion'], [];
```

Query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_UNION_AGG(ARRAY_CAT(Animals, Herbs)) AS Result
FROM t
```

or:

```
SELECT ARRAY_UNION_AGG(Animals) AS Result
FROM (SELECT Animals FROM t 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Herbs FROM t);
```

Output:

[image]

---

You could flatten the combined array and then aggregate back:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT F."VALUE") AS unique_things
FROM tab, TABLE(FLATTEN(ARRAY_CAT(tab.Animals, tab.Herbs))) f
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your requirements right and assuming the source tables of

```
insert into tabarray select array_construct('cat', 'dog'), array_construct('basil');
insert into tabarray select array_construct('lion', 'dog'), null;
```

I would say the result would look like this:

```
select array_agg(distinct value) from
(
  select
    value from tabarray
  , lateral flatten( input => col1 )
  union all
  select
  value from tabarray
  , lateral flatten( input => col2 ))
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation to handle NULLs in case they appear in data set.

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT a.VALUE) unique_things from tab, TABLE (FLATTEN(array_compact(array_append(tab.Animals, tab.Herbs)))) a
```